# Hiding a View after it was tapped

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to hide a view after it was tapped. In order to do so, I'm using touchesBegan to detect if the view was tapped and if it was, it should perform an action such as hiding the view and the view on top of it. These two views are defined:

```
   @IBOutlet weak var theDarkView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var theFinalView: UIView!
```

And here is the code that I came up with.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //-- hides the view whenever its touched
        if let touch = touches.first {
            if touch.view == self.theDarkView {
                if theDarkView.isHidden == false || theFinalView.isHidden == false {
                    theDarkView.isHidden = true
                    theFinalView.isHidden = true
                }
            } else {
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

**If you could help me out and show me the correct way to go about this and also show me where I messed up with my method, that would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: What seems to be problem?

Comment: in which view theDarkView and theFinalView exist ?

Comment: Your code works. If you touch the theDarkView set hidden to the two views.

Comment: you want to hide the self also ?

Comment: The views aren't hiding when I press on them & they're connected to the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Your code works. When you tap on the theDarkView all the views are setted to hidden.

If in your project it doesn't works, you must connect the IBOutlet on the storyboard.

**EDIT:**

If the views are embedded in a scrollView it doesn't works because the UIScrollView intercepts these touches events.

The solutions are subclass the UIScrollView or use the `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of `touchesBegan`.

A possible code solution is to add in the viewDidLoad this:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapRecognized))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
tapGesture.isEnabled = true
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false
theDarkView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

to add the tapGesture to your view and then add the method:

```
@objc func tapRecognized() {
    if red.isHidden == false || blue.isHidden == false {
        red.isHidden = true
        blue.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I've connected the screens but they're not hiding once they're tapped on

Comment: If you create a new project view with only two views and your code, after tapping on **theDarkView** it works without problems. Only a question: are the views free or are they embedded in a view that intercept the touch like scrollView o tableView?

Comment: they're embedded in a scroll view

Answer (score 0):

No problem with your code this accomplish the same job also

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
     theDarkView.isHidden = touches.first?.view == self.theDarkView 
     theFinalView.isHidden = theDarkView.isHidden
}
```

Comment: Am i supposed to add something to viewDidload? I feel like Im missing something that connects the touchesBegan method. I used it once before and it used to work but I think Im missing code for it

Comment: **touchesBegan** is called freely no any configurations , if you have a problem with your current upload to github as i think this should work